# "startGrabbing: Node is not writable." in pylon_camera package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I try to launch the pylon_camera node, I receive the following error:

> startGrabbing: Node is not writable.

I traced through the code and found that an exception is thrown when the node is trying to set the PixelFormat to Mono8 using the setValue function in pylon_camera_base.hpp in the startGrabbing function.

I'm using the basler ace acA4600-7gc GigE camera with pylon 5 sdk. I can view the camera images and set camera parameters just fine using the PylonViewerApp.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Michael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237591/%22startgrabbing:-node-is-not-writable.%22-in-pylon_camera-package/) by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-21**:
You might want to report this on the `pylon_camera` package [issue tracker](https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera/issues). Do please report back if/when you receive a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reported the problem as suggested by @[gvdhoorn](http://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/)

They promptly committed a bugfix:

https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera/commit/d38db1fb136d1733ff364f75a294cdb30c4f4895

All is well now after an update!

---

Originally posted by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) with karma: 91 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1